# Why is the error "unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#play-plugins-redis_2.11;2.3.0" with the Play Redis plugin?

Tags: redis, sbt, playframework-2.3

I decided to use [Play Framework Redis Plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/redis) but i got the following error:

> [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#play-plugins-redis_2.11;2.3.0: not found

why?

Answer (score 1):

It has not been released yet.

http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/plugins/
https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/pull/125#issuecomment-53961989

Answer (score 0):

The correct dependency is:

```
"com.typesafe.play.plugins" %% "play-plugins-redis" % "2.3.0"
```

Comment: I have used this dependency!

Comment: Note the difference in `groupId` - `com.typesafe.play.plugins` is correct while `com.typesafe` is not. Can you show the entire `build.sbt`?